# Extract DD, MM ,YYYY, HH, MI separately

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have an Excel sheet as my source file in which one of the column has date and time together in the format MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI. How do I extract MM,DD ,YYYY, HH, MI separately in Informatica PowerCenter?

Answer (score 2):

Send the input field e.g.DATEPORTNAME to an expression transformation with 5 new output ports

I.e. For the month port use: TO_CHAR(DATEPORTNAME, 'MM')
For the day port use: TO_CHAR(DATEPORTNAME, 'DD')
year: TO_CHAR(DATEPORTNAME, 'YYYY')
hours:TO_CHAR(DATEPORTNAME, 'HH')
minutes:TO_CHAR(DATEPORTNAME, 'MI')

Comment: In the fact table, I have to extract MOU. The aggregation is done using Customer_ID. In the target field I can see the value for MOU for the first occurence of the Customer_ID, if the Custom,er_ID is repeated more than once,the MOU is not gettind added in the target. However, the revenue generated by each Customer (with morw than one occurence ) is calculated properly. Any help with the MOU ?

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct and raise this new query in a new question? Also if you can explain in that question what MOU is, what you are grouping by on the aggregator (which ports have group by ticked?) and what the expression is to calculate revenue generated (and whether the calculation is done in the aggregator)